# Adobe Air - Delete XML entry

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air

How to delete an XML entry with Adobe Air?

This is how my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ENTRY "IMG_ID="01042012"/>
    <ENTRY "IMG_ID="03052012"/>
    <ENTRY "IMG_ID="09052012"/>
```

This is my code to load the XML:

```
var xmlGallery:XML

    function readGalleryXml(e:Event = null):void
    {
        var fileGallery:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("gallery.xml");
        if (fileGallery.exists)
        {
            var streamGallery:FileStream = new FileStream();
            try
            {
                streamGallery.openAsync(fileGallery,flash.filesystem.FileMode.READ);
                xmlGallery = new XML(streamGallery.readUTFBytes(streamGallery.bytesAvailable));
            }
            finally
            {
                streamGallery.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks. Uli

Comment: You shouldn't use `openAsync` without listening for the open event; just use `open` instead.

Comment: Ok, but how to delete an XML entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roll your own delete child function as described [here](http://edsyrett.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/xmlremovechild/):

```
 public static function deleteNode(node:XML):void
 {
     if (node != null && node.parent() != null)
     {
         delete node.parent().children()[node.childIndex()];
     }
}
```

Comment: You can also just use the `delete` operator, similar to deleting properties from an `Object`